# Global variable synchronization between threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, communication, semaphore

I am developing a robot controlled by Arduino. It will be receiving command from a program on my PC over TCP and forward to Arduino via serial communication. Once Arduino execute the command, it sensors mounting on it will return the environment status to PC. Then program will run some algorithm to decide what action to take next. I am able to receive directional command to move the robot manually from an Android application. I am using Raspberry Pi as the messages passing/control device.

Program on PC, Android application and Arduino sketch are complete and tested. But the communication issue among several threads in the program running on Rpi persists.

So far I have the following (the TCP, serial, bluetooth socket codes are omitted as they are out the scope of this question):

```
int canForwardToPC, recvFromPC, recvFromAndroid, recvFromAr, canSendCommand, isWaitingForInstruc, isWaitingForPos;

//all the int are initialized to be 0

void *ar_send(){
    int status;

    do{
        if(canSendCommand){
            status = write(ser, output, BUFFER_SIZE);
            if(status != -1) {

                printf("Sent to Arduino: %s\n", output);

                memset(&output[0], 0, sizeof(output));

                isWaitingForGridStr = 1;
                canSendCommand = 0;

                usleep(1000000);

            }else{
                ar_isConnected = 0;
                printf("Error Writing\n");
            }
        }
    }while(1);

}

void *tcp_send(){

    int status;

    do{
        if (canForwardToPC && tcp_isConnected){
            status = write(newsockfd, output, strlen(output));
            printf("Sent to PC: %s\n", output);
            memset(&output[0], 0, sizeof(output));
            if (status > 0) {

                isWaitingForInstruc = 1;
            }

            else{
                tcp_isConnected = 0;
                usleep(10000000);
            }
            canForwardToPC = 0;
        }
    } while (1);

}

void *bt_recv(){

    int bytes_read;

    do{
        bytes_read = read(client, bt_buffer, sizeof(bt_buffer));
        if(bytes_read > 0) {

            printf("Received \"%s\" from Android\n", bt_buffer);
            recvFromAndroid = 1;

        }
        else{

            bt_isConnected = 0;

        }
    }while(1);

}

void *ar_recv(){

    do{
        if(isWaitingForGridStr){

            n  = read(ser, ar_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

            if(n <= 0) continue;

            ar_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = '\0';

            printf("Received %s from Arduino.\n", ar_buffer);

            isWaitingForGridStr = 0;

            recvFromAr = 1;

        }
    }while(1);

}

void *tcp_recv(){

    do{
        if (tcp_isConnected && isWaitingForInstruc){


            n = read(newsockfd, tcp_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);


            isWaitingForInstruc = 0;

            printf("Received %s from PC.\n", tcp_buffer);
            if (n > 0){
                recvFromPC = 1;

            }else{
                tcp_isConnected = 0;
                usleep(10000000);
            }
        }
    } while (1);

}

void *controller(){
do{
    if(recvFromAndroid){

        recvFromAndroid = 0;



        char temp[1];
        temp[0] = bt_buffer[0];

        canForwardToPC = 1;

        strncpy(output, temp, sizeof(temp));
        memset(&bt_buffer[0], 0, sizeof(bt_buffer));


    }

    else if(recvFromAr){

        recvFromAr = 0;


        canForwardToPC = 1;

        isWaitingForInstruc = 1;]

        strncpy(output, ar_buffer, sizeof(ar_buffer));
        memset(&ar_buffer[0], 0, sizeof(ar_buffer));

    }

    else if(recvFromPC){

        recvFromPC = 0;

        canSendCommand = 1;

        strncpy(output, tcp_buffer, sizeof(tcp_buffer));
        memset(&tcp_buffer[0], 0, sizeof(tcp_buffer));

    }

    }while(1);

}
```

Each method is one thread and will be created and joined in the main function.

From what I see, output are well protected by all the integers and the receive and send threads are organize properly. The code seems legit.

But I have the following partial output which is not as planned:

```
Sent to PC: W1
Received W1 from PC.
Sent to Arduino: W1
Received 0:0:0:2:0:3 from Arduino.
Sent to PC: 0:0:0:2:0:3
Received W1W1W1W1W1D180W1A180W1 from PC.
Sent to Arduino: W1W1W1W1W1D180W1A180W1
Received -1:0:-1:2:0:3 from Arduino.
Received W1D180W1A180W1W1W1W1A180 from PC.
Sent to PC: -1:0:-1:2:0:3
Received W1 from PC.
Sent to Arduino: W1
Received -1:-1:-1:-1:0:3 from Arduino.
Received W1D180W1D180W1W1W1A180W1 from PC.
Sent to PC: -1:-1:-1:-1:0:3
Received W1 from PC.
Sent to Arduino: W1
Received -1:-1:-1:-1:0:3 from Arduino.
Received D180W1W1W1W1W1W1D180W1 from PC.
Sent to PC: D180W1W1W1W1W1W1D180W1
Received A180 from PC.
Sent to Arduino: A180
Received -1:-1:-1:1:0:3 from Arduino.
Sent to PC: -1:-1:-1:1:0:3
Received W1W1W1D180W1W1W1W1 from PC.
Received W1 from PC.
```

The only thing I want to send to PC is the position string, which is in the form x:x:x:x:x:x. But there is an instance where D180W1W1W1W1W1W1D180W1 is sent to PC.

The expected output should be repeatedly as the following:
Send to PC
Receive from PC
Send to Arduino
Receive from Arduino

I suspect that there occur some global variable inconsistency that caused the unexpected output.

I have found severals articles about semaphore and mutex but those are solutions for 2 threads only. I have 6 threads running here and I have no idea how to implement semaphore.

What can I do to resolve the data inconsistency problem?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unsynchronized, non-readonly, non-atomic access to shared objects in multiple threads is undefined behavior.

Comment: Mutual exclusion among N processes? You might implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm. But exactly why you would need that? Perhaps the better course is to restructure your code.

Comment: I don't understand why you have 6 threads in your program. It seems like an odd design choice for a system that communicates between 2 devices, or is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: @o_weisman since the program is running on rpi. it basically forward messages from a device to another. each of the threads handles different thing. ar_send handles outgoing message to arduino; ar_recv handles incoming message from arduino; tcp_send handles outgoing message to pc; tcp_recv handles incoming message from pc; bt_recv handles incoming message from android. all the logic for when to forward the meesage, and where the message will be forwarding to is controlled by controller. any idea to eliminate some of the threads and make it simpler?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have told me: 
You should implement a different queue of messages for each incoming and outgoing channel. Each communication thread, is only responsible for placing incoming messages into the queue, or taking message from the queue and sending them out on its communication port. Each queue will have its lock (mutex or whatever). A main controller (1 thread) will have access to all the queues, and will handle moving the messages between them. The mutex for each queue will be locked either by the controller or by its communication thread.

Example of process:

1. Message is received by thread handling read from PC.
2. It places it in the queue of incoming messages from PC after acquiring its lock and then releases the lock.
3. Controller wakes up (either by periodic scheduling which I recommend, or by some event mechanism) and tries to acquire the lock of the queue of incoming messages from PC.
4. It gets the lock and reads the first message there. It discovers that it has a message to arduino.
5. It takes the message, releases incoming from PC lock.
6. Gets outgoing to arduino lock, and puts message in outgoing to arduino queue.
7. Send to arduino thread wakes up, gets its queue lock, gets all messages there and sends to arduino.
8. Send to arduino thread releases lock and goes to sleep.

All outgoing threads can be made to process periodically or upon event from the controller.
Hope this helps.